# How do I get my articles to float Left

Tags: html, css

I am not a front-end developer, but for an HTML5 course I am taking I am trying to understand some HTML5 and styling. 
I have the following code: these are the beginning of articles which will be side-by-side with image and text, my question is, how do I get them lined up side by side?

```
   <div>
        <section> 
        <article>
        <header><h1>article 1</h1></header>      
        <p>Some Text</p>
        </article>
       </section> 
       <section>
        <article>
        <header><h1>article 2</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        </article>
        </section>
        <section>
       <article>
        <header><h1>article 3</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        </article>
        </section>
        </div>
```

Also, how do I get the `<p>` under the heading, right now it is off to the left side of the header?

Comment: Depends on your browser support needs (IE10+), you may want to have a look at flexbox.

Comment: I have IE 11 installed

Comment: Have you tried any CSS?

Comment: I will be doing that... I just don't know what the properties are to make this happen

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't use a `<section>` for each `<article>`, instead, you probably want a the `<section>` to replace your `<div>` and have all articles nested inside of it as siblings, like so:

```
<section>
    <article>
        <header><h1>article 1</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header><h1>article 2</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header><h1>article 3</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

---

As for putting them side by side, the best option would be using flexbox (see **[browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)**)

Here's what I came up with:

```
<style type="text/css">
    section {
        display: flex;
    }

    section article {
        flex: 1 100%;
    }
</style>

<section>
    <article>
        <header><h1>article 1</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header><h1>article 2</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header><h1>article 3</h1></header>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

With `flex: 1 100%;` you make sure the 3 take all of the horizontal space of their container.

Read more: **[CSS-Tricks: A complete guide to flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Comment: this is starting to work, but Article 1 is off of the left side of page. but thank you for getting me to this point